# Removing cache files when app is removed ios

Tags: ios, caching

I'm wondering about removing cache files I've stored inside my app. The directory is made in Documents, beyond the app's folder. Is it possible to write code inside app that will be executed when iOS removes the app from system? Can it be done without storing files beyong app's cache directory?

Thank for any answer. I'm working in emulator so what path should be to make directory in app tmpFolder to not take care about leftovers after deleting app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you aren't informed about an app's deinstallation / removal BUT nothing except iCloud and keychain survives the removal - especially not some app's caches

your app runs in a sandbox with its own library, caches and documents folder